# Can I view sublayers of an AI file inside of After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I have an AI file consisting of a few different elements (like a windmill, a house with a solar panel, etc.). I have different items (take the house, for instance)separated by a top-level layer, with many sub-layers within the top level.  When I import this into After Effects, I end up only being able to see my top layers, cannot figure out any way to view the sublayers.  Is there any way to view these sublayers within AE?  The basic kind of animation I am trying to pull off requires having access to individual parts of each vector (IE I need to have access to just the fan blades on the windmill, not the blades, and stand together).

So far all I can see as a solution is to pull out all my sub-layers and name them all accordingly..which if that is the only solution then that works, but I would love to not have to do this if there is another and more simple way!

Thanks for any input!!